# How to add timeout to this async function

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise, timeout

I want to add a timeout such that if any of these "tasks" takes longer than 5 minutes, it should stop that function and resolve the promise. I've been struggling a bit, any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
if (require.main === module) {
  (async () => {
    const tasks = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= NB_PARALLEL; i++) {
      tasks.push(buildReferenceSpaceCollection(json));
    }
    const results = await Promise.all(tasks);
    console.log(results);
    process.exit(0);
  })().catch(console.error);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a `wait`-function that rejects after the given amount of time and then use `Promise.race` on that `wait`-function and your `Promise.all`. Now, if your promises inside `Promise.all` take longer than the `wait`, `Promise.race` will reject, otherwise the resolved values will be assigned to `results`.

```
function wait(ms) {
    return new Promise((_, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
           reject(new Error("wait time exceeded"));
        }, ms);
    })
}

(async () => {
    const tasks = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= NB_PARALLEL; i++) {
      tasks.push(buildReferenceSpaceCollection(json));
    }
    // 5 mins in ms
    const wait5MinPromise = wait(5*60*1000);
    const results = await Promise.race([wait5MinPromise, Promise.all(tasks)]);
    console.log(results);
    process.exit(0);
  })().catch(console.error)
```

;

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: Happy to help, please don't forget to accept the answer by clicking the checkmark on the left, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun ([Live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/cpromise-all-concurrent-u5pr8?file=/src/index.js)):

```
import { CPromise } from "c-promise2";

const generateYourAsyncTaskHereToAddInQueue= async (value)=> {
    console.log(`Inner task started [${value}]`);
    await CPromise.delay(1000);
    return value;
}

(async () => {
    const results = await CPromise.all(function* () {
        for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            yield generateYourAsyncTaskHereToAddInQueue(`Task result ${i}`);
        }
    }, {concurrency: 3}).timeout(5000);

    console.log(`results:`, results);

    return results;
})().catch(console.error);
```